# Cassandra write path

Tags: cassandra, datastax

There is one question on the Cassandra practice exam (https://academy.datastax.com/node/1291/take):

«Which of the following statements about writes is incorrect?»

1. Writes that do not meet the consistency requirements are not
   rolled back
2. A replica node needs to write to both the Commit Log and Memtable
3. Any node in the Cassandra cluster can act as a coordinator for
   client requests
4. Cassandra sends write requests to the minimum number of replica
   nodes needed to fulfill consistency requirements

Answer «4» is marked as «true». But I assume that is not correct, and «1» is the correct answer.
Please explain this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independent of the CL, the coordinator will send the write to all replicas. The CL controls how many responses are required before the coordinator responds to the client.